# WIndows 10 UWP - How can I determine if a Key press is a letter or number?

Tags: uwp, keypress

Windows 10 UWP: Example: On UWP grid, a button1.content = 1 and a textbox. Using mouse to press button1.content, 1 is shown in the textbox.text.
How to simulate numeric keypad (1) and 1 is shown in the textbox.text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `TextBlock.Text` to set the text to `TextBlock`.

If you want to know the key press, you should add `KeyDown` in `Grid`

```
<Grid KeyDown="Grid_OnKeyDown"></Grid>
```

And add the following code

```
private void Grid_OnKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var str = e.Key.ToString();
    if (char.IsDigit(str[0]))
    {
        //is digit
    }
    // is letter
}
```

You can use `TextBlock.Text = xx` to set the `TextBlock`.

Comment: Hi user3079834: Thank you for quick answer: 
private void Grid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
           var key = e.Key.ToString();
          
            if (char.IsDigit(key[0]))
            {
                //is digit
                txtbxStatus.Text = "Is digit";
            }
            else
            {
                // is letter
                txtbxStatus.Text = "Letter";
            }
            txtbxStatus.Text = txtbxStatus.Text + " " + key;
}